# Overriding UILabel font causes cut off label

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel, interface-builder

I'm creating a custom `UILabel` class. The reason why is because I want to adjust the properties of a Label with a `Constants` class. Modifying properties in IB can become cumbersome once the primary color of the app changes. Anyways this is my custom UILabel class:

```
@IBDesignable class FormTitleLabel: UILabel {

    override var font: UIFont! {
        get {
            return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36, weight: .heavy)
        } set {
            super.font = font
        }
    }
}
```

This causes the label to appear cut-off:

[image]

I can fix this by using the following code:

```
@IBDesignable class FormTitleLabel: UILabel {

    override var font: UIFont! {
        get {
            return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36, weight: .heavy)
        } set {
            super.font = font
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setup()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

        setup()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)
    }

}
```

Why does this solution work?

Comment: What is a `Constants` class?

Comment: @RaffAl A struct that defines global constants in the Application. An example is "primaryColor" or "borderColor".

Comment: appear where in IB or in device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is simply wrong:

```
override var font: UIFont! {
    get {
        return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36, weight: .heavy)
    } set {
        super.font = font
    }
}
```

You're always returning font `A`, but internally setting font `B`. View drawing functions check the font of the label to draw text and they use font `A`, although in reality, they should use font `B`. That's why you have this weird behaviour.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. I want IB to display the visual changes I'm setting internally without them being able to get modified. Is this approach correct?